# NuGet 3.0 and dependencies based on architecture

Tags: .net, nuget, visual-studio-2015

With NuGet 3.0, package dependencies are now specified in project.json instead on being listed in the proj file. Looking under “NuGet 3.0 and ‘project.json’” in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/07/30/universal-windows-apps-in-net.aspx it seems that it may be possible to specify different dependencies for different architecture. Am I correct in thinking that? If it is possible, how is it done? I tried adding different dependencies under different the runtimes but it did not work.

Another question coming from a different angle, I tried to overcome the above problem by doing the trick under “x86, x64 and ARM ?” in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mim/archive/2013/09/02/packaging-a-windows-store-apps-component-with-nuget-part-2.aspx as I have the code for the binaries I need but it does not work. With NuGet 3.0 is there a way to do such a thing?